# Strange interference between two TikZ pictures with common "\tikzset"

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please, consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,chains,scopes}

\tikzset{
  node distance = 10mm and 30mm,
    on grid,
    start chain = A going below,
    start chain = B going below,
 myright/.style = {draw, minimum height=4ex, minimum width=33mm,
                   on chain=A},
  myleft/.style = {draw, fill=cyan!30, minimum height=4ex,
                   on chain=B}
        }

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% LEFT
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={myleft}]
\node {X}; % name=B-1
\node {Y};
\node {Z};
    \end{scope}
% RIGHT
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={myright}]
\node [right=of B-1]    {belong to X}; % name=A-1
\node {belong to Y};
\node {also belong to /};
\node {belong to no one};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

 some text

\begin{tikzpicture}
% LEFT
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={myleft}]
\node {X}; % name=B-1
\node {Y};
\node {Z};
    \end{scope}
% RIGHT
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={myright}]
\node [right=of B-1]    {belong to X}; % name=A-1
\node {belong to Y};
\node {also belong to /};
\node {belong to no one};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

In above MWE are two identical codes for picture. Why the generated pictures are not the same?

[image]

Comment: The scope of the chains you've defined is the entire document! `start chain` is relative to the current scope. If that's the entire document, the chain is effectively global. It is maybe not so surprising you then get unexpected results.

Comment: Meaning, that I need to move most of `\tikzset{ ... }` from preamble to each TikZ picture? I will check this! ... It is sufficient to move only `start chain = ...`. Thank you for clarifying this. Please, convert your comment to answer, that I can accept it.

Comment: Or you could put the start stuff into a `.code` and so have the chain actually started by passing a key to the `tikzpicture` but, yes, the actual execution of the `start chain` needs to be within the scope you want the chain active in. At least, that's how I understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`start chain` defines a chain as active within the current scope. If this is the entire document, that's the scope. So, in the second picture, `B-1` does not refer to the node you think. However, it doesn't cleanly refer to the node in the first picture either, because no `remember picture` was given, so `B-1` is where `B-1` would be if it was drawn in this picture, which it isn't.

To see what is going on, add `\draw [red] (B-1) -- (B-2);` to the second picture:

[image: joining ghost nodes in red]

Clearly, what is joined is the non-node `B-1` and the non-node `B-2` because `B-1` and `B-2` do not really exist in this picture and the `right=of...` is relative to the scope of this picture and not the scope of the chain.

The node you mean in the `right=of` is actually `B-4`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,chains,scopes}

\tikzset{
  node distance = 10mm and 30mm,
  on grid,
  start chain = A going below,
  start chain = B going below,
  myright/.style = {draw, minimum height=4ex, minimum width=33mm, on chain=A},
  myleft/.style = {draw, fill=cyan!30, minimum height=4ex, on chain=B}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % LEFT
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={myleft}]
    \node {X}; % name=B-1
    \node {Y};
    \node {Z};
  \end{scope}
  % RIGHT
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={myright}]
    \node [right=of B-1]    {belong to X}; % name=A-1
    \node {belong to Y};
    \node {also belong to /};
    \node {belong to no one};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

some text

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % LEFT
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={myleft}]
    \node {X}; % name=B-1
    \node {Y};
    \node {Z};
  \end{scope}
  % RIGHT
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={myright}]
    \node [right=of B-4]    {belong to X}; % name=A-1
    \node {belong to Y};
    \node {also belong to /};
    \node {belong to no one};
  \end{scope}
  \draw [red] (B-1) -- (B-2) -- (B-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: joining ghosts and positioning relative to non-ghosts]